# Is it possible to create dynamic user permissions in S3 and How?

Tags: objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I've a iOS app and I would like my users to upload images to `S3` directly.

I need `UserX` to be able to upload folders to `__MY_BUCKET__/UserX/*` Only. So that each one of my users have their own folder and only they can modify content in them.

Given that scenario I need to create *dynamic permissions to my S3 bucket*

Is that possible?

If it is... maybe I am in the right path or not....

What I've done so far is

I am using [this](http://aws.amazon.com/code/7351543942956566) guide to create `Elastic Beanstalk` with a `Token Vending Machine`. Then I used [this](http://aws.amazon.com/code/4598681430241367) other guide to configure the `TVM`.

Now my issue with that in none of the guides it shows an example of how to register a dynamic user (my app user) or how get the token from the `TVM` or how to say "Hey TVM, this userID needs upload access to `__BUCKET_/ThiUserID/*`" from a iOS app.

So I guess what I wonder, is how do I fill the gaps if what I am trying to achieve is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm one of the maintainers of the AWS Mobile SDKs.  [The page you linked to](http://aws.amazon.com/code/4598681430241367) includes projects for both iOS and Android that show how to integrate the customized TVM code in a mobile application.  I suggest you look there and if you need further clarification, please update your with specific questions about the code.

You may also want to look at our [web identity federation](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/4617974389850313) sample which is included with the SDKs.  In combination with IAM policy variables, you can generate dynamic policies without the use of a Token Vending Machine.